# Validity of statement about any discrete distribution of data

Tags: statistics, means, standard-deviation

In a textbook, I've come across the following statement without proof:

> In ***any*** group of data, most of the data are within 3
> standard deviations of the mean.

This is equivalent to saying that $$P(m-3s,m+3s)>.5,$$ where m is mean, s is the (population) standard deviation of ***any*** finite set of data. Is this true and if so, can someone point me to a proof?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality

Comment: Very cool, thanks.